# Having difficulty closing a PopUP window, after update and submit button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

So, I have a javaScript that calls an ASP page, using ShowModalDialog ... it works great, passes the correct information, the user is then prompted with radio button to answer a question, then if the user presses "submit" ... the data is written to a SQL table. this all works; however, I cannot get the window to close. The behavior is the program opens another page (same content as in the window popUP) only it is full page size.
When I tried to add the following code: Response.Write("script language='javascript'?window.close();") ... I get the same behavior with a message indicating that the program is trying to close the window. 
this is so frustrating because I don't understand why closing a window is so diffcult. 
Please help if you can.

Comment: Do you Try `YourModal.Hide();` from code behind?

Comment: Instead of processing the SQL from within the modal, would it be easier to set the radio choice as the returnValue of the window and close it, then handle the SQL in the original page? Or you could use a webservice call instead of a postback as it's easier to have the complete method fire the javascript close

Comment: I found that this issue is isolated to IE8, it works fine in Google Chrome. Thank you for the response, I will try it. Regards,

Comment: where in the code behind do I put the modal.hide()?

Comment: I switched from using showModalDialog() to using .fancybox in jquery. Works like a charm!! so easy! thanks for all of your assistance.